# Customizing Reveal js

Tags: jquery, html, css, reveal.js

js for html presentations, everything is working fine.

I just wanted to ask if there any way to resize it so that it can be embedded in a page and if there is any way by which I can control the presentation on the page only .. not by opening the full page presentation?

Comment: ...what? Post code and/or jsFiddle please.

Comment: im just asking that can i resize a reveal.js presentation??

Comment: I doubt anyone here is going to go to the effort of setting up a local project and providing you with a solution. You need to create a JSFiddle or post code showing what you have so far and have tried. From SO Help: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."